# How to split this code into 2 pages

Tags: php, curl

I have a form that when submited posts to remote url using curl the form post to it self and all works well but I know need to send the form data to a page for prossesing spliting the form code from the prossesing code has not worked.

my current code which works is.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['btnApply_x'])) {
    $post['AffiliateID'] = '0000';
    $post['AffiliatePW'] = '00000';
    $post['ReqMode'] = 'TEST';
    $post['ReqLoanAmount'] = $_POST['slidval'];
    $post['ReqConsent'] = 1;
    $post['ReqIPAddress'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $post['AppTitle'] = $_POST['ddlTitle'];
    $post['AppFirstName'] = $_POST['txtFirstname'];
    $post['AppLastName'] = $_POST['txtSurname'];
    $post['AppEmail'] = $_POST['txtEmail'];
    $post['AppDOBDay'] = $_POST['ddlDay'];
    $post['AppDOBMonth'] = $_POST['ddlMonth'];
    $post['AppDOBYear'] = $_POST['ddlYear'];
    // $post['date_of_birth'] = $_POST['ddlDay'] . '/' . $_POST['ddlMonth'] . '/' . $_POST['ddlYear'];
    $post['AppHomePhone'] = $_POST['txtHomePhone'];
    $post['AppWorkPhone'] = $_POST['txtWorkPhone'];
    $post['AppMobilePhone'] = $_POST['txtMobile'];
    // $post['BankDebitCard'] = $_POST['ddlDMPlan'];
    $post['BankDebitCard'] = $_POST['ddlPrimaryDebitCard'];
    $post['AppHomeStatus'] = $_POST['ddlHomeType'];
    $post['btnnext_x'] = $_POST['btnnext_x'];
    $post['btnnext_y'] = $_POST['btnnext_y'];
    $post['AppHouseNumber'] = $_POST['txtHouseNumber'];
    $post['AppStreet'] = $_POST['txtStreetName'];
    $post['AppTown'] = $_POST['txtTownCity'];
    $post['AppPostCode'] = $_POST['txtPostCode'];
    $post['AppCounty'] = $_POST['ddlCounty'];
    $post['AppAddressYears'] = $_POST['ddlTimeAtAddress'];
    $post['EmpIncomeType'] = $_POST['ddlPrimaryIncome'];
    $post['EmpEmployerName'] = $_POST['txtEmployerName'];
    $post['EmpTimeAtEmployer'] = $_POST['ddlTimeWithEmployer'];
    $post['EmpNetMonthlyPay'] = $_POST['txtAfterTax']; //needs changing
    // $post['following_pay_day'] = $_POST['ddlFollowingPayDay'] . '/' . $_POST['ddlFollowingPayMonth'] . '/' . $_POST['ddlFollowingPayYear'];
    $post['EmpPayFrequency'] = $_POST['ddlPayFrequency'];
    $post['EmpDirectPayment'] = $_POST['ddlPaidIntoBankAccount']; //change this
    // $post['next_pay_day'] = $_POST['ddlNextPayDay'] . '/' . $_POST['ddlNextPayMonth'] . '/' . $_POST['ddlNextPayYear'];
    $post['EmpNextPayDay'] = $_POST['ddlNextPayDay'];
    $post['EmpNextPayMonth'] = $_POST['ddlNextPayMonth'];
    $post['EmpNextPayYear'] = $_POST['ddlNextPayYear'];
    $post['EmpFollowingPayDay'] = $_POST['ddlFollowingPayDay'];
    $post['EmpFollowingPayMonth'] = $_POST['ddlFollowingPayMonth'];
    $post['EmpFollowingPayYear'] = $_POST['ddlFollowingPayYear'];
    $post['EmpNINumber'] = $_POST['txtNationalInsurance'];
    $post['BankAccount'] = $_POST['txtAccountNumber'];
    $post['BankSortcode'] = $_POST['txtSortCode'];
    // $post['chkTerms'] = $_POST['chkTerms'];
    $post['ReqMarketingOptIn'] = $_POST['chkMarketing'];
    // rint_r($post);
    $post['ReqAgent'] = '';
    $post['ReqDomain'] = '';
    $post['AppAddressMonths'] = 1;
    $post['ReqTotalTimeout'] = 60;
    $post['ReqLenderTimeout'] = 60;
    $postvars = str_replace('&amp;', '&', (http_build_query($post)));

    $ch = curl_init('https://000.co.uk/requestservice.asmx/Requestv4');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST , 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , $postvars);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , 0); // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE , 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1); // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
    $Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);

    $redirect = cut_str($Rec_Data, '<RedirectURL>', '</RedirectURL>');
    if (empty($redirect)) {
        echo $Rec_Data; //change this line to reflect any changes / error messages to be displayed
    } else {
        header('location:' . $redirect);
    }
}

function cut_str($str, $left, $right)
{
    $str = substr (stristr ($str, $left), strlen ($left));
    $leftLen = strlen (stristr ($str, $right));
    $leftLen = $leftLen ? - ($leftLen) : strlen ($str);
    $str = substr ($str, 0, $leftLen);
    return $str;
}

?>
<form target="_blank" action='' method="POST"  >
<input type='hidden' value='' name='AffiliateID' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AffiliatePW' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='ReqMode' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='ReqTotalTimeout' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='ReqLenderTimeout' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='ReqLoanAmount' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppTitle' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppFirstName' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppLastName' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppEmail' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppDOBDay' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppDOBMonth' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppDOBYear' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppHomePhone' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppWorkPhone' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppMobilePhone' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppPostCode' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppHouseNumber' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppStreet' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppTown' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppCounty' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpIncomeType' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpEmployerName' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpTimeAtEmployer' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpNetMonthlyPay' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpPayFrequency' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpDirectPayment' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpNextPayDay' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpNextPayMonth' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpNextPayYear' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpFollowingPayDay' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpFollowingPayMonth' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpFollowingPayYear' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpNINumber' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='BankAccount' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='BankSortcode' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='BankDebitCard' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppAddressYears' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppAddressMonths' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppHomeStatus' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='ReqConsent' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='ReqIPAddress' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='ReqAgent' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='ReqMarketingOptIn' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='ReqDomain' />
<input type="submit" value="Invoke" class="button">
```

What I need to do is have to pages one just for the form and a secand which prosses the form

Comment: I believe spitting is forbidden by the [content policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy) :D Or at least it should ... it's disgusting :p

Comment: Sorry for my bad spelling i take it firefox spellcheck dose not work on this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create another php file and use [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) or [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to include it.

Answer (score 1):

On your form page, just make the form action field point to your process page:

```
<form action='your_process_page.php' method="POST">
```

And move all your processing code to that page.